# Video upload not working php

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to upload a video too be saved on my server(or locally for now) for later display on the website. I am struggling around every turn and figured i should ask for help. For now i am trying to simply upload an image but i realized that uploading a video is a bit more complicated and will address that matter after my current problem.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="dropzone" method="POST" action="/upload/questions" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="file_upload" type="file" name="txtAddVideo">
</form>
```

Below is my php( there are a bunch of debugging echos in there to display some information that might help.

```
        echo $_FILES['txtAddVideo']['name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_FILES['txtAddVideo']['type'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_FILES['txtAddVideo']['size'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_FILES['txtAddVideo']['tmp_name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_FILES['txtAddVideo']['error'];
        echo "<br>";


        $uploaddir = '/mp4';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['txtAddVideo']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtAddVideo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

        echo '<pre>';
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtAddVideo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
        }

        echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
        print_r($_FILES);

        print "</pre>";



        exit();
```

Here is the result of the controller's code after attempting to upload.

```
Tavern.jpg
image/jpeg
290164
C:\xampp\tmp\php1E96.tmp
0
Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [txtAddVideo] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tavern.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1E96.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 290164
        )

)
```

My folder permission i do believe is set to be writable. I right clicked the folders and un-ticked the read-only checkbox.

It seems to be successful in the upload but doesn't save it to a folder.

> NOTE: I am using laravel but not composer.

Comment: You're running `move_uploaded_file()` twice. After the first time, you won't be able to move the same file again since it's already moved (don't exist in that folder anymore).

Comment: You should also dump your variable `$uploadfile`. It doesn't look correct. You're starting with a slash (which means the root of the file system) and then you append the filename without a slash between it and the folder `mp4`, so it should give you something like: `/mp4the-file-name.ext`